# I want to run a Java program with gif image background in raspberry pie

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3

It's a simple program that I've coded.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class image extends JFrame {
    ImageIcon icon;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    public image() {
        icon = new ImageIcon("/home/pi/Desktop/image/rain.gif");
        JPanel background=new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
                setOpaque(false);
                super.paintComponent(g);
                repaint();
        }
        };
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(background);
        setContentPane(scrollPane);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        image frame = new image();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But this only shows the white screen when the jar file is executed.
Additionally, I used the ristretto viewer instead of the imageview in the raspberry pie.
I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Check if you are using correct path. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Maybe try without `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: I succeeded in doing it without 'super.paintComponent(g);' Thank you @Gyro Grearless. But what does this method play?